# How do I read SAML 2.0 ( running on apache server) authentication details into my Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, saml

I built a rails application and i hosted this application with SAML 2.0 authentication which is in apache environment. Now I want to read username(I can see it in SAML header browser plugin), that SAML authenticates in rails application and display. Could you please help me in how to get user id from SAML after user successfully authenticated to application.

Comment: Are you implementing some saml related gem in you app?

Comment: I mean, I did not add any thing as of now, but planning to add ruby-sam. Could you suggest me any other gem

Comment: I've used ruby-saml to implement SSO with OneLogin. Tried omniauth-saml, but had some issues with devise.

Comment: Ok, here I am not using devise. I am using login page of apache web server. and the authentication with LDAP. Once the user is authenticated, he can view the rails application.  but here my challenge is to read user id ( which he giving in authentication page - apache web server) in rails application. This i am trying with ruby-saml gem.